# How can I transform each 7 row to single row in csv file with python?

Tags: python

csv file example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
```

new csv file which I want:

```
1    2    3    4    5    6    7
8    9    10   11   12   13   14
15   16   17   18   19   20   21
```

Note: I want tab between each numbers.

Comment: you iterate through the file, at every 7th line ready (use mod 7), write to file.

Comment: Addition to @JoeFerndz comment: You need to apply some additional line formatting in order to get the desired output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: What did you try so far? Stackoverflow is not a code writing platform. However, if you provide a sample code snippet showing us where you are stuck, we will be glad to help you.

Comment: Research "chunking".

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', header=None)
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1, 7))
df.to_csv("output.csv", sep="\t", header=False)
```

output `df`:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| 1 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
| 2 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 |

Comment: Neat !!! pandas is a good and quick solution for this

Answer (score 0):

```py
file = open("yourFile.csv", "r")
newFile = open("newFile.csv", "w")

for line in file.read().strip().split("\n"):
    newFile.write(line)
    if (int(line) % 7 == 0):
        newFile.write("\n")
    else:
        newFile.write("\t")

file.close()
newFile.close()
```

Comment: you should not consider the value in the file instead the row numbers. So use enumerate instead of computing based on `line`

Comment: since i/o operation is costlier, try to minimize the i/o operation and use memory to store the temp data (write once every 7 rows read instead of writing every time)

Answer (score 0):

I would have preferred that you show your work first before I post the answer.

Here's the answer anyway so it gives you some pointers to solve this.

```
with open('abc.txt', 'r') as f1, open ('xyz.txt','w') as f2:
    write_line = ''
    for i, line in enumerate(f1):
        line = line.strip()
        if i != 0 and i %7 == 0:
            write_line += '\n'
            f2.write(write_line)
            write_line = line + '\t'
        else:
            write_line += line + '\t'
    if i != 0 and i %7 != 0:
        f2.write(write_line)
```

Keep track of the row you read. If the row is the first one (i==0), just add the line + `\t` to a temp variable. If the line is the 8th / 15th / ... (i%7 ==0), then you have read 7 rows already. So write the data into the output file. Then reset the temp variable so you can do this again.

Once you are out of the loop, you want to make sure you write the last set of rows. Sometimes the file may end up having 20 rows. So you want to ensure you write the last 6 rows into the output file.

The output of this will be:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   
8   9   10  11  12  13  14  
15  16  17  18  19  20  21
```

If the input file had values from 1 thru 24, the output file would look like this:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   
8   9   10  11  12  13  14  
15  16  17  18  19  20  21  
22  23  24
```